# Newbie: Keras with TensorFlow MNIST code sample: wrong predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mnist

(Attempt #2, see below for history)

I'm a total newbie with Deep Learning and Keras, and trying to play with the MNIST sample, following the tutorial at https://elitedatascience.com/keras-tutorial-deep-learning-in-python.

With regard to that sample, I just made some minimal adjustments to the code, to make it compatible with the latest API. Then, I added a sample Python script which loads the saved model and a BMP image file (specified as the script first argument), and outputs the class prediction in the form of an exit code.

I trained the model getting accuracy 0.9911, and saved it.

Yet, when testing with some BMP samples I get inconsistent results: only some of the digits are recognized correctly. Probably I'm missing something obvious in preprocessing my data. After Toyo's reply, I changed both the scripts, following https://nextjournal.com/schmudde/ml4a-mnist, so here I quote the newer versions. The older ones are at the bottom.

I also added a sample visualization of the preprocessed array representing an image, and looking at it I can see the digit, 'white on black', as expected (in the predict preprocessing I added color inversion by setting each value equal to 255-value, as my input BMP are 'black on white').

Yet, the issue is still there.

Thanks!

#### New Scripts

Training:

```
# numpy with a specific seed for reproducibility
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)

# keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.datasets import mnist

# load pre-shuffled MNIST data into train and test sets
# MNIST: 60k samples of 28x28 grayscale (0-255) images,
# and additional 10k samples for test.
((x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)) = mnist.load_data()
n_train, height, width = x_train.shape
n_test, _, _ = x_test.shape
print('x_train shape: {}'.format(x_train.shape))
print('n_train: {}'.format(n_train))
print('height: {}'.format(height))
print('width: {}'.format(width))
print('n_test: {}'.format(n_test))

# we require shape (count, height, width, channel), where count
# is the count of our samples, and channel is the number of channels,
# here equal to 1 as these are grayscale images (for RGB it would be 3).
x_train = x_train.reshape(n_train, height, width, 1).astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.reshape(n_test, height, width, 1).astype('float32')

# normalize from [0, 255] to [0, 1]
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255

# show image array
print('Sample array: {}\n'.format(x_train[0].shape))
print(x_train[0])
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(x_train[0].reshape(28, 28))
plt.show()

# the labels need to be converted into one-hot vectors,
# which are nc-element arrays (nc is the number of classes),
# which are 0 for all classes except 1 for the class the label
# is assigned to.
# convert integer labels into one-hot vectors
n_classes = 10
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, n_classes)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, n_classes)

# define model architecture.
model = Sequential()

# number of convolutional filters
n_filters = 32

# convolution filter size
n_conv = 3

# pooling window size
n_pool = 2

# (1) convolution
model.add(Convolution2D(
        n_filters, 
        kernel_size=(n_conv, n_conv),
        # we have a 28x28 single channel (grayscale) image
        # so the input shape should be (28, 28, 1)
        input_shape=(height, width, 1)
))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Convolution2D(n_filters, kernel_size=(n_conv, n_conv)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# apply pooling to summarize the features extracted thus far
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(n_pool, n_pool)))

# (2) connected layers
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

# flatten the data for the 1D layers
model.add(Flatten())

# Dense(n_outputs)
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# (3) the softmax output layer gives us a probablity for each class
model.add(Dense(n_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

# how many examples to look at during each update step
batch_size = 128

# how many times to run through the full set of examples
n_epochs = 10

model.fit(x_train,
          y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=n_epochs,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

# how'd we do?
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)

print('loss:', loss)
print('accuracy:', accuracy)

# save the model. Use load_model(path) to load it later
model.save('/projects/python/mnist/mnist.h5')
```

Prediction:

```
# get the path to the image to be recognized from 1st arg
import sys
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Missing image file path')
    exit(-1)

# load the pretrained MNIST model
print('Loading model...')
import numpy as np
import keras
model = keras.models.load_model('/projects/python/mnist/mnist.h5')

# load the image ensuring that its size is 28x28
print('Loading image ' + sys.argv[1])
from keras.preprocessing import image
x = image.load_img(sys.argv[1], color_mode='grayscale', target_size=(28, 28))

# convert image to NumPy array
x = image.img_to_array(x, data_format='channels_last')
print('np from image:\n')
print(x.shape)
print(x)

# add a major dimension to represent the number of samples, i.e. 1
x = x.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1)
# convert data type to float32 and normalize 0-255 values to range [0, 1]
x = x.astype('float32')
# invert colors, we need white on black
x = 255 - x
x /= 255
print('np before predicting:\n')
print(x.shape)
print(x)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(x.reshape(28, 28))
plt.show()

# predict
classes = model.predict_classes(x)
print(classes[0])
exit(classes[0])
```

#### Old scripts

```
# numpy with a specific seed for reproducibility
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.datasets import mnist
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# load pre-shuffled MNIST data into train and test sets
# 60k samples of 28x28 images
((x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)) = mnist.load_data()

print(x_train.shape)
plt.imshow(x_train[0])
input("Press enter to continue...")

# preprocess input data, as Theano requires explicit depth:
# from shape (n, width, height) to (n, depth=1, width, height)
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, 28, 28)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, 28, 28)
# convert our data type to float32 and normalize our data values to the range [0, 1]
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255

# convert 1-dimensional class arrays (with values 0-9)
# to 10-dimensional class matrices (with values 0-1)
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

# define model architecture
model = Sequential()

# input_shape is the shape of each single parameter:
# here it is depth=1, width=28, height=28
# 32 convolution filters
# 3 rows in each convolution kernel
# 3 cols in each convolution kernel
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(1, 28, 28), data_format="channels_first"))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', data_format="channels_first"))
# reduce the model's parameters by sliding a 2x2 pooling filter
# across the previous layer and taking the max of the 4 values in the 2x2 filter
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
# regularize the model to prevent overfitting
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

# flatten (make 1-dimensional)
model.add(Flatten())
# dense: 128=output size of the layer
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
# final layer has size 10 for the 10 digits
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

# compile model (loss function and optimizer)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# fit model on training data
model.fit(x_train, y_train, 
          batch_size=32, nb_epochs=10, verbose=1)

# evaluate model on test data
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)

# save the model. Use load_model(path) to load it later
model.save('/projects/python/mnist/mnist.h5')
```

The consuming script:

```
# get the path to the image to be recognized from 1st arg
import sys
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Missing image file path')
    exit(-1)

# load the pretrained MNIST model
print('Loading model...')
import numpy as np
import keras
model = keras.models.load_model('/projects/python/mnist/mnist.h5')

# load the image ensuring that its size is 28x28
print('Loading image ' + sys.argv[1])
from keras.preprocessing import image
x = image.load_img(sys.argv[1], color_mode='grayscale', target_size=(28, 28))

# convert image to NumPy array
x = image.img_to_array(x, data_format='channels_first')
# add a major dimension to represent the number of samples, i.e. 1
x = x.reshape(1, 1, 28, 28)
# convert data type to float32 and normalize 0-255 values to range [0, 1]
x = x.astype('float32')
x /= 255
print(x.shape)
print(x)

# evaluate
classes = model.predict_classes(x)
print(classes[0])
exit(classes[0])
```

Comment: You specified Tensorflow in your title but your input data shape does not match. It should be (X, 28, 28, 1). Issues that I had when predicting with trained model were : number being too big so you can resize to (22, 22) and pad to get the 28x28 size, applying dilation (cv.dilate(data, (5,5))) can improve your accuracy, also make sure that your input data are made of a white number and black background.

Comment: Thank you very much, I hadn't realized that I had to make white digit and black background, plus my other errors. Anyway, I have now (supposedly) adjusted the code, but I still experience the same inconsistencies. I have edited my post to include the new code.

Comment: Could you add the image you are using for prediction ? That would help.

Comment: Here are the 10 digits I'm using: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsHCfliT740PkYRasSG0_2Q9Ai67Eg (black on white, 28x28, grayscale BMP). I also add the H5 model: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsHCfliT740PkYRb95c_iaooHZDFOg .

Comment: all digits except 5/7/8 are correctly recognized. The accuracy you report is the test one ? Dilation didn't help and the overall size seems ok. One last problem you might have is about the size ratio. Additional steps you could use would be to add data augmentation, make your model more complex, add batch normalization...

Comment: Thanks, the accuracy is from line "loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)" in the above training script. It seems odd that, with a value beyond 99% on thousands of MNIST samples, 3 of 10 samples of mine happen to be unrecognized.

Comment: It is not so odd as the MNIST dataset is pretty much filled with numbers that have a particular aspect ratio. If you feed your model with numbers that have a different aspect ratio, it will fail.